# composite function with conditional IF

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, relations

I've been wrapping my head around my Computer and Logic Essentials class, I can do most composite functions, however there is one question that I'm confused with.

It has an if statement inside it:

```
f: R → R, f(x) = 4x – 3
g: R → R, g(x) = x2 + 1
h: R → R, h(x) = 0 (if x ≥ 0), h(x) = 0 (if x < 0)
determine:
(a) f º f - done, confirmed correct
(b) f º g - done, confirmed correct
(c) h º f - confused
(d) h º g - confused
```

The first two were easy because they don't have that conditional. One thing i'm confused about is they both say 0 (if condition), on both accounts. Shouldn't they be a different value, otherwise the function will always return a 0?

Secondly, the answer is supposedly:

```
(c) (h º f) (x) = 1 if x ≥ ¾, (h º f) (x) = 0 if x < ¾
(d) (h º g) (x) = 1
```

for c, it states `1 if... 0 if...` So i'll assume it's a typo in the question (is this a valid assumption?) If so, then h now becomes: `h: R → R, h(x) = 1 (if x ≥ 0), h(x) = 0 (if x < 0)`


Alright. Now when it comes to the answer, I have **no idea** how on earth they came up with x is `≥ ¾`

What i've come up with so far is:

```
h o f = h(f(x)) = h(4x-3) 
= 1 (if(4x-3) >= 0, 0 (if(4x-3) < 0)
```

this seems like the rational first step to the problem, since I should be replacing `x` with the function as no value is given for `x`.


Can someone please explain how they came up with the `3/4` figure? And how that was used to solve the question (c)? Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{3}{4}$ is the value of $x$ such that $f(x)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know everything. Yes, it seems a *typo*.
$$4x-3\ge 0 \iff 4x\ge 3 \iff x\ge 3/4\,.$$
So,  for $h\circ f=\ x\mapsto h(f(x))$, we have to calculate $h(4x-3)$. 
By def. of $h$, this is $1$ if $4x-3\ge 0$, i.e. if $x\ge 3/4$.

For part (d), observe that $x^2+1\ge 1\ge 0$ for all real $x$.

Comment: well for example `f o f`, I have `f(f(x)) = f(4x - 3)`. That's what i mean with "replacing x with the function", I'm not sure of the correct terminology. I'm pretty new to set theory,  if I recall an arrow means `x implies y`... a double arrow means `x implies y, y implies x`... However, since I'm new to set theory I don't really understand how `4x - 3 >= 0` implies `x >= 3/4. Would you be able to please show this in a way a dummy like me could understand? >_<

Comment: Yes, for $h\circ f(x)$ we check $h(4x-3)$. This is $1$ if $4x-3\ge 0$, i.e. if $x\ge 3/4$.

Comment: please note that i updated my comment, after you replied: Edit: I think i figured out out: `4x - 3 >= 0`... `4x > 0 + 3`... `x >= 3/4`. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. First we added $3$ to both sides of the inequation, then we divided both sides by $4$. These steps preserve the inequality.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If you don't mind helping again, I'm trying to do part (d), however I don't exactly understand what you mean. This is what i tried: `h o g = h(g(x)) = h(x^2 + 1) = 1(if (x^2 + 1) >= 0), 0 (if (x^2 + 1 < 0)`... Thus, if i square root both sides of the `x^2 + 1`, I'm left with `= 1 (if x >= -1), 0 (if x < -1)`.. However, after this step, I'm not sure what to go in order to get the result `h o g = 1`. Can you show me how to get that answer? Thanks.